# Cannot access mounted drive in some apps

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I have had to set up my Ubuntu system again after some issues and want to mount a partition of by big drive for easy access. I had it before at /data

I have added it to fstab

```
UUID=da4bd237-85df-4811-ad3a-997419506567 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=ec9ea02e-8da1-4044-8442-53300f958000 /data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I can access it fine via Files and load documents in LibreOffice, but Audacity just does not see /data at all. Permissions look fine.

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Jul 18 18:22 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 Jun 15 21:10 cdrom/
drwxrwxrwx  19 root root       4096 Mar  6  2018 data/
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root       5000 Jul 22 21:32 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 132 root root      12288 Jul 22 21:31 etc/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like less of a mounting/filesystem problem and more of an Audacity problem. How did you install Audacity? Could you post the output of `type -a audacity`?

Comment: Ah, it's a snap. I used the other one in the software store and that works. I did not realise that snaps are that limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that Audacity was a snap. Using the regular version from the reps works. This is the before and after.

```
audacity is /snap/bin/audacity
steve@zaphod:~$ type -a audacity
audacity is /usr/bin/audacity
audacity is /bin/audacity
steve@zaphod:~$
```

Comment: How do you change from snap to reps?

Comment: For some packages both are an option. Snaps seem to be limited in what parts of the file system they can access. Maybe there is some way to work around this if you don't store stuff in /home

Comment: Since I asked, I discovered that one can configure permissions for snapped applications, so far that does fine.
Sometimes I install using GUI sometimes using apt from Terminal, it seems to differ also, but I'm satisfied.

Comment: @GuyEllisHreinberg It's great you have found a solution, but it's quite a shame you don't share it with others.